# Gradle error : peer not authenticated while building command line

Tags: android, qt, gradle

I have a QtApp that I am building for android using gradle. Note that I am building it **command line** on **OSX** using the tool `androiddeployqt` using the following command.

`$androiddeployqt --sign MyKey.keystore gevupc --storepass somePassword --output android --verbose --input android-libMyQtApp.so-deployment-settings.json`

After resolving proxy issues with gradle, it gives me the following error now

```
Unzipping /var/lib/jenkins/gradlesettings/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.2.1-all/2m8005s69iu8v0oiejfej094b/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip to /var/lib/jenkins/gradlesettings/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.2.1-all/2m8005s69iu8v0oiejfej094b
Set executable permissions for: /var/lib/jenkins/gradlesettings/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.2.1-all/2m8005s69iu8v0oiejfej094b/gradle-2.2.1/bin/gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android-build'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0.
     Required by:
         :android-build:unspecified
      > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.1.0/gradle-1.1.0.pom'.
     > peer not authenticated

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

**Can someone suggest how to get rid of this issue ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the repositories listed in the buildscript block. Using the following block resolves the issue squarely.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'maven'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven  {
            url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    }
}
```

`url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"` is a repository dependency that gradle 2.1.3 is able to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

It notmally happens if there is a problem with your internet connection.

Ensure you configured the proxy properly and check your internet connection. Direct to the address it mentions to see if you can access it through browser .

Comment: It says it cannot get `https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.1.0/gradle-1.1.0.pom` . but I am able to `wget` the link on command line. Strange that it fails when gradle tries to reach. Not able to get what is the real problem here

Comment: If you can access by terminal it surely is something wrong with your proxy configuration in gradle delete the proxy and check again. No dout.

Comment: Proxy was an issue due to which it wasn't able to download `http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip`, but i fixed that in `gradle.settings` in GRADLE_USER_HOME`.     Will upgrading to gradle 3.1 help ?